# Javascript onclick changing id img

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to have it so that if you select one of the images of id 'defaultone' or 'defaulttwo' then the image with id 'actualone' is changed to that.  I know I am very close, but I have a small error somewhere.  Can someone please help me??

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Popup window code
        function newPopup(url) {
            popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=450,width=600,left=10,top=10,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
        }
        function bigimg(x) {
            x.style.height="65px";
            x.style.width="85px";
            x.style.opacity="0.5";
        }
        function defaultimg(x) {
            x.style.height="60px";
            x.style.width="80px";
        }
        function teamback(x) {
            document.getElementById("x").src = document.getElementById("defaultone").src;
        }
        </script>

    </head>
        <body>
            Your Team <img id="defaultone" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this)" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="cowboys.gif"> vs <img id="defaulttwo" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this)" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="giants.gif"><img src="" id="actualone" style="width:85px; height:65px;"><br><br>
            <img src="colts.gif"> vs <img src="bears.gif">
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see the x element in your code.

Comment: Then you should not have double quotes, x.id

Comment: Why are you changing the id? Why not keep the id, but change the class instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JavaScript method `teamover()`, you are incorrectly referencing the sending-element with `document.getElementById("x")`; Element `"x"` doesn't exist.

Try updating to this:

```
function teamback(x) {
    // update the "actualone" image's source to the sending-image's source
    document.getElementById("actualone").src = x.src;
}
```

Comment: lmao newfurniturey has pulled :P

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery (that you have already included in the head of your HTML document):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // For both
        $('#defaultone, #defaulttwo').click(function(){
            $('#actualone').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Rewritten to use one function.

Comment: Can you come up with a way so that it only has one of those inner functions for both...like the answer above but in jquery..

Comment: Hmm... give me a minute and I'll rewrite it

Answer (score 0):

It should be as follows

```
function teamback(x) {
    x.src = document.getElementById("defaultone").src; // To change the x element's src to defaultone's src
}
```

Since you are passing the element itself using `this` not the id of it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access `x` on this line:

```
document.getElementById("x").src =
```

It should be:

```
x.src =
```

Also, the code in `onclick`, etc. should have a semicolon after it, like

```
onclick="teamback(this);"
```